# Alter View not recognizing column

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have scripts for adding columns to tables which worked.

When I run scripts to alter views with the new column the script fails because the columns are not recognized

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure UniqueTempDispositions, Line 76
Invalid column name 'servicerequestid'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure UniqueTempDispositions, Line 47
Invalid column name 'servicerequestid'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure MergeDispositions, Line 54
Invalid column name 'ServiceRequestID'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure NonPIICachedDispositions, Line 18
Invalid column name 'ServiceRequestID'.
```

Any reason why?  Am I missing something?

I've started and stopped the server, I've relogged in to no avail.
ORIGINAL SCRIPT:

```
alter view 
dbo.UniqueTempDispositions 
as 
SELECT     QuotaGroup, Country, ServiceGroup, Language, ContactChannel, TrackingID, CONVERT(DATETIME, CaseClosedDate) AS casecloseddate, MSFTRep, CustEmail,  
                      CustPhone, CustomerName, ProductFamily, ProductSubType, CONVERT(DATETIME, CandidateReceivedDate) AS candidatereceiveddate, CONVERT(INT, SurveyMode)  
                      AS surveymode, CONVERT(DATETIME, SurveyWaveStartDate) AS surveywavestartdate, CONVERT(DATETIME, SurveyInvitationDate) AS surveyinvitationdate,  
                      CONVERT(DATETIME, SurveyReminderDate) AS surveyreminderdate, CONVERT(DATETIME, SurveyCompleteDate) AS surveycompletedate, CONVERT(DATETIME,  
                      OptOutDate) AS optoutdate, CONVERT(DATETIME, SurveyWaveEndDate) AS surveywaveenddate, CONVERT(INT, DispositionCode) AS dispositioncode, SurveyName,  
                      SurveyVendor, COUNT(*) AS countofunique, BusinessUnitName, UploadId, MIN(LineNumber) AS LineNumber, BusinessUnitSubgroup, ServiceRequestID 
FROM         DispositionReporting.dbo.tempDispositions AS td 
GROUP BY QuotaGroup, Country, ServiceGroup, Language, ContactChannel, TrackingID, CONVERT(DATETIME, CaseClosedDate), MSFTRep, CustEmail, CustPhone,  
                      CustomerName, ProductFamily, ProductSubType, CONVERT(DATETIME, CandidateReceivedDate), CONVERT(INT, SurveyMode), CONVERT(DATETIME,  
                      SurveyWaveStartDate), CONVERT(DATETIME, SurveyInvitationDate), CONVERT(DATETIME, SurveyReminderDate), CONVERT(DATETIME, SurveyCompleteDate),  
                      CONVERT(DATETIME, OptOutDate), CONVERT(DATETIME, SurveyWaveEndDate), CONVERT(INT, DispositionCode), SurveyName, SurveyVendor, BusinessUnitName,  
                      UploadId, BusinessUnitSubgroup, ServiceRequestID 
go
```

I ended up dropping and re-adding the view which worked, just don't understand the other way around:

```
use DispositionReporting
go
drop view dbo.UniqueTempDispositions
go
create view
dbo.UniqueTempDispositions
as
SELECT     QuotaGroup, Country, ServiceGroup, Language, ContactChannel, TrackingID, CONVERT(DATETIME, CaseClosedDate) AS casecloseddate, MSFTRep, CustEmail, 
                      CustPhone, CustomerName, ProductFamily, ProductSubType, CONVERT(DATETIME, CandidateReceivedDate) AS candidatereceiveddate, CONVERT(INT, SurveyMode) 
                      AS surveymode, CONVERT(DATETIME, SurveyWaveStartDate) AS surveywavestartdate, CONVERT(DATETIME, SurveyInvitationDate) AS surveyinvitationdate, 
                      CONVERT(DATETIME, SurveyReminderDate) AS surveyreminderdate, CONVERT(DATETIME, SurveyCompleteDate) AS surveycompletedate, CONVERT(DATETIME, 
                      OptOutDate) AS optoutdate, CONVERT(DATETIME, SurveyWaveEndDate) AS surveywaveenddate, CONVERT(INT, DispositionCode) AS dispositioncode, SurveyName, 
                      SurveyVendor, COUNT(*) AS countofunique, BusinessUnitName, UploadId, MIN(LineNumber) AS LineNumber, BusinessUnitSubgroup, ServiceRequestID
FROM         DispositionReporting.dbo.tempDispositions AS td
GROUP BY QuotaGroup, Country, ServiceGroup, Language, ContactChannel, TrackingID, CONVERT(DATETIME, CaseClosedDate), MSFTRep, CustEmail, CustPhone, 
                      CustomerName, ProductFamily, ProductSubType, CONVERT(DATETIME, CandidateReceivedDate), CONVERT(INT, SurveyMode), CONVERT(DATETIME, 
                      SurveyWaveStartDate), CONVERT(DATETIME, SurveyInvitationDate), CONVERT(DATETIME, SurveyReminderDate), CONVERT(DATETIME, SurveyCompleteDate), 
                      CONVERT(DATETIME, OptOutDate), CONVERT(DATETIME, SurveyWaveEndDate), CONVERT(INT, DispositionCode), SurveyName, SurveyVendor, BusinessUnitName, 
                      UploadId, BusinessUnitSubgroup, ServiceRequestID
go
exec sp_refreshview 'dbo.UniqueTempDispositions'
go
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [how to make sure that the view will have the underlying table changes by using sp_refreshview](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/how-to-make-sure-that-the-view-will-have)

Did you run sp_refreshview against the views after you made changes to the tables?